# Activity not displaying until UDP packet received

Tags: java, android, udp, android-activity, android-networking

I'm making an application that receives UDP messages. The issue I'm having is around displaying the `Activity`, as it only displays after receiving a `UDP` message. In `onCreate` I have `startUdp()` which starts listening for `UDP` messages and I think this is the issue.

Is there a way to tell when the `Activity` has finished loading or where I should start listening?

My `Activity` code:

```
public class UDPActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_UDP);

        // Setup the UDP stuff
        startUDP();

        System.out.println( "Sent Response of ");

        TextView rowLetter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rowLetter);
        TextView seatNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seatNumber);
        Button btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Binding Click event to Button
        btnClose.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //Closing SecondScreen Activity
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_make_light, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private static final int UDP_SERVER_PORT = 12345;
    private static final int MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN = 1500;

    private void startUDP() {
        Log.d("UDP", "S: Connecting...");
        String lText;
        byte[] lMsg = new byte[MAX_UDP_DATAGRAM_LEN];

        DatagramSocket ds = null;
        while (true) {
            try {
                ds = new DatagramSocket(UDP_SERVER_PORT);
                //disable timeout for testing
                //ds.setSoTimeout(100000);
                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(lMsg, lMsg.length);
                Log.d("UDP", "S: Receiving...");

                ds.receive(dp);
                lText = new String(lMsg, 0, dp.getLength());
                Log.i("UDP packet received", "S: Recieved '" + lText);
                textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

                textView.setText(lText);
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (ds != null) {
                    ds.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code in order to clarify your question pls!

Comment: Does `startUdp()` block?

Comment: You should fix your question to be in a better format. But, you can use the Log commands to see where your code has gone. `Log.e("UDP", "+++ AFTER STARTUDP +++");` after the startUdp() call, if the program reaches that line of code it will come up in your LogCat.

Comment: It blocks while inside startUDP() while it is receiving UDP messages. Once it receives one message the rest of the view displays. I can see it wait to receive the message before anything displays on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do networking on the UI thread, move it to something such as an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as a simple solution you could just call `startUdp()` in `onResume()` instead of 'onCreate()`.

But if it really blocks doing network I/O, it is likely that Android will just kill your application because it is blocking the main (UI) thread.

You should run the UDP listener in a separate thread, or use AsyncTask and have it pass any received UDP packet data to the main thread using a handler for display purposes.